# How to flag any unsupported LINQ operator for LINQ-to-Entity at build time

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Today, a fellow team member checked-in some code that looked like this

```
var query = repository.GetQueryable<Customer>()
.OrderBy(c => c.Name)
.Select( (c, i) => new{Order = i, Customer = c});
```

Obviously, this query is not going to work against Entity Framework since that particular overload of Select method is [unsupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) .
The problem is that you won't know about any possible usage of unsupported methods until runtime.

Is there a way to get some sort of feedback during build time? I'm thinking about writing a custom FxCop rule but thought ask this question on Stackoverflow in case someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have integration tests which run your LINQ queries against actual databases?

That's where I'd start to put the effort - that way you'll be testing the whole query; not just which overloads of the query operators are supported, but whether the *contents* of the various clauses are supported too.

Comment: That is a very good advice. It's quite interesting how some dev teams moved on from just integration tests to just unit tests in the past few years.
Just out of curiousity, I'll give it another day in case someone has a solution that doesn't require a real database.

Comment: With EF we are moving back to integration tests because unit tests with mocked EF features don't provide necessary validation.

Comment: @Payman: I'm not suggesting moving *away* from unit tests - I'm suggesting *augmenting* unit tests with integration tests.